# How to move image in Applet?

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, awt

I want to move the character left, right up, and down in [applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2zU6.png), but it is not moving at all.  here is my code, help please

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class drawCenter extends Applet
{
    private int x,y;// the x and y of the position of the player
    private BufferedImage image, pos;

    public void init(  )
    {
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("pokemonCenter.png"));
            pos = ImageIO.read(new File("player/maleInGame.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

        }
        x = 150; y = 171;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        switch( keyCode )
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP: if( y>0 )
            {
                y=y-19;
                repaint();

            }

            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: if( y<171 )
            {
                y=y+19;
                repaint();

            }

            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:if( x>0 )
            {
                x=x-15;
                repaint();

            }

            break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:if( x<285 )
            {
                x=x+15;
                repaint();

            }

            break;
        }
        e.consume();
    }

    public void keyReleased(){

    }

    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(pos, x, y, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might attend to the [8 or so points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12233117/418556) I made on another thread you started.

Comment: *"How to move image in Applet?"*  Exactly the same as you might do in the application you **should** be developing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretending to have a KeyListener, but there is no KeyListener anywhere to be found, much less one added to a component of the GUI. Your solution: create a class that implements KeyListener or that extends KeyAdapter, and then add it to a GUI component that has focus.

Please check out: [How to Write a KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Also, I recommend that you avoid having your GUI class, your Applet, implement KeyListener since that can give the class too much to be responsible for. Better I think to either create an anonymous inner class or even a separate stand-alone class for your KeyListener.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class implement [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and then call `super.addKeyListener(this)` in your constructor. As you have it now, you're neither specifying the class implements the interface (despite implementing the methods it would need to) nor are you ever registering a listener with the `Applet`.

Comment: Why do you recommend he use super?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels makes more sense to me. Plus, if I were to advocate premature optimization, `invokespecial` is quicker than `invokevirtual` ;-)

Comment: Could you please elaborate me `invokespecial` and `invokevirtual`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati the difference is rather insignificant... it was intended as a joke. If you really want to learn, how about you read the JVM Specification?

Comment: @veer I didn't read any specifications and I'm not an student of computer science. I've just learning Java for fun

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati I'm a high-school student :-p but the major difference is that `invokevirtual` does a look-up through an object's virtual dispatch table (i.e. vtable); `invokespecial` instead doesn't need to.

Comment: @veer Don't tell me you are 16. :)

Comment: @veer Where did you learn programming so well? Or better question: when?

Comment: @brano88 I began to program after reading other peoples' code and just searching for articles on the Internet around the age of 9... though I wouldn't say I program much better than anyone else :-p

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

public class DrawCenter extends JApplet implements KeyListener {

    Image character = null;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public Image loadImage(String name){
        return new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(name)).getImage();
    }

    public void init(){
        character = getImage("pokemonCenter.png");
        x = getWidth()/2 - character.getWidth(null)/2;
        y = getHeight()/2 - character.getHeight(null)/2;
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        switch (e.getKeyCode()){
            case VK_LEFT: x--; break;
            case VK_RIGHT: x++; break;
            case VK_UP:    y--; break;
            case VK_DOWN: y++; break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(character, x, y, null);
    }

}
```

If you're making a game see the game loops or try a `Game-Engine (If you'r interested, go to
http://game-engine-for-java.googlecode.com/ )`

Comment: Where are the rest of KeyListener method's? :)

Comment: @brano88 Just removed them to make the answer short

Comment: Oops! I've forgotten that. I thought that he could add the others

Answer (score 0):

You should be something like this:

```
package stack;


import java.applet.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class DrawCenter extends Applet implements KeyListener{

    private int x=50,y=50;// the x and y of the position of the player


    public void init(  ){ 
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        switch( keyCode ) { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP: if( y>0 ){ //when up key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
                                y=y-19;
                                repaint();
                            }
                            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: if( y<171 ){//when down key is pressed and the position of the player is not on the edge
                                    y=y+19;
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:  if( x>0 ){
                                    x=x-15;
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: if( x<285 ){
                                    x=x+15;
                                    repaint();
                                }
                                break;
        }
    } 

    public void keyReleased(){

    }


    public void paint( Graphics g ){ //will draw the background and the character
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `e.consume()`? It would not allow swing to process it's other functions.

Comment: Oh...it seems I forgot to remove it when modifying his code. I will fix it.

Comment: the character is still not moving

Comment: Just click on surface of Applet and it will move by pressing arrow key's.